# How to join 3 tables using SQL code in C# - Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

I have 3 tables in my SQL database (`EmployeeMaster`, `TripPayroll`, `Deduction`).

I need to reflect in the 1st 3 columns of my DataGridthe IDNo, LastName, FirstName of all employees in `EmployeeMaster`. Then in the 4th column of the DataGrid, I want to sum the amount from `TripPayroll` of the IDNo of employee in the 1st column. The code should sum the amount from `TripPayroll` with the same IDNo as in the 1st Column. Then in the 5th column of the DataGrid, I want to sum all the amount from Deduction Table of the with the same IDNo as in the 1st column but if the IDNo has no corresponding IDNo in the Deduction Table, the value is 0.00. then in the 6th column, I want to get the difference by subtracting the Amount in `TripPayroll - Deduction`.

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbaseConnection2"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
con.Open();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT EmployeeMaster.IDNo, EmployeeMaster.LastName, EmployeeMaster.FirstName, COUNT(TripPayroll.DTRNo) AS No_Trip, SUM(TripPayroll.Rate) AS Gross_Pay, ISNULL(SUM(Deduction.Amount),'0.00') AS Deduction, SUM(TripPayroll.Rate)-ISNULL(SUM(Deduction.Amount),'0.00') AS Total_Pay FROM EmployeeMaster LEFT JOIN TripPayroll ON EmployeeMaster.IDNo = TripPayroll.IDNo LEFT JOIN Deduction ON EmployeeMaster.IDNo=Deduction.IDNo WHERE (TripPayroll.DeliveryDate <= '" + PayrollCutOff.Text + "') AND (TripPayroll.Status = 'Complete') GROUP BY EmployeeMaster.LastName, EmployeeMaster.FirstName,EmployeeMaster.IDNo", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);


Payroll_List.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: What **RDBMS** are you using? Please add a relevant tag. Also: please post the **table structure** so that we have something to go on...

Comment: and what have you tried so far ??

Comment: looking like you got a homework to do. At least provide ERD of the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Em.IDNo,Em.LastName,Em.FirstName,Sum(TP.Amount),IsNUll(Sum(dc.Amount),0),(Tp.Amount - Dc.Amount) as AmountDiff
from EmployeeMaster Em
Inner join TripPayroll TP 
on Em.IDNo = TP.IDNo
Inner join Deduction dc
on EM.IDNo = dc.IDNo
```

Try this. Hope You will get some idea from this solution.